# aquaris m10 connect to macbook pro

Tags: aquaris, m10

I have the Meizu 4 Ubuntu Edition OTA-12 and can connect it to a Macbook Pro via android File Transfer and transfer files without any problem . When I try the same with my Aquaris M10 I get the message: Cannot connect to device.
What I am doing wrong?
Thanks, Gerd

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following. On my Macbook Pro, I opened the terminal and typed in: system_profiler SPUSBDataType
The system recognized the Aquaris M10 HD. Following, I opened Android File Transfer, and now everything works fine.
Gerd